# How to display results with Javascript and cgi, besides <iframe> and <object>?

Tags: javascript, html, cgi

I have an input form which in realtime display the results from three different cgi-based lookups.

My first approach was to have three iframes which i change the .src for every search, which works but feels unnecessary:

```
<iframe id="iframe1">
document.getElementById("iframe1").src="/cgi-bin/one.cgi";
```

My second approach was having three object:s which have their .data changed, but that also feels and looks bad:

```
<object id="object1">
document.getElementById("object1").data="/cgi-bin/one.cgi";
```

Both of the above examples works - functionally, but I would like to know a better way to do it. For example how do I get the same results using DIVs ? I.e. no iframe:s or object:s.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The alternative is to use [AJAX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_(programming)). This means that you have to create and send an `XMLHttpRequest`. When the response is received, you have to put it into a `<div>`.

Here's a minimalistic example:

```
var div = document.getElementById("results");

var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4) {
        if (this.status == 200) {
            div.innerHTML = this.responseText;
        } else {
            div.innerHTML = "<h1>Error " + this.status + "</h1><p>The content could not be loaded.</p>";
        }
    }
};
xhttp.open("GET", "/cgi-bin/one.cgi", true);
xhttp.send();
```

For cross-browser compatibility, I recommend to use [this function](https://gist.github.com/Xeoncross/7663273) or the [jQuery ajax function](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/).